# Count the number of logins of all users

Tags: arrays, mongodb, count, find

I have been looking through the Mongo documentation, but can't seem to figure out how to do the following.

I have a number of documents which are user in my mongoDB. I also store the time of their login. The basic structure of my document is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "5649d78a3701a14f0da852d1",
  "email": "email@domain.com",
  "logins": [
  {
    "_id": "56585cd2d869365ba532cfdd",
    "logintime": "2015-11-27T15:54:19.000Z",
    "typelogin": "website"
  },
  {
    "_id": "56585cfaa52ebe65a58d2feb",
    "logintime": "2015-11-27T15:54:19.000Z",
    "typelogin": "website"
  ]}
}
```

So as you can see, each time a user logs in, I store this in an array "logins".

What I want to do is count the occurences of all logins after a specific date. For example, all logins as of yesterday.

When I run:

```
db.find({ "logins.logintime": { "$gte": new Date("2015-11-07T00:00:00.000Z")}},{ _id: 0, logins: {$elemMatch: { "typelogin": "website"}}});
```

I get only one document returned. This is not correct, as there are more logins, but find only returns one document. I guess I have to aggregate and push the results in a new array, but I'm not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregation, like this:

- step 1: unwind the logins
- step 2: match the logins
- step 3: group and count

  ```
  db.dbname.aggregate([
      {$unwind: "$logins"},
      {$match: {
          "logins.logintime": {$gte: "2015-11-27T15:54:19.000Z"}, 
          "logins.typelogin": "website"
      }},
      {$group: {
          _id: "$email", 
          logins: {$sum: 1}
      }}
  ])
  ```

This will return, using sample data above:

```
{ "_id" : "email@domain.com", "logins" : 2 }
```

Comment: Great, that solved the problem. Although I had to use this:

    new Date("2015-11-27T00:00:00.000Z")

Would it also be possible to sum the total number of logins? Now I get an array with all e-mail addresses and the amount of logins of this user. But what if I want to sum this last part?

Comment: Never mind, if I replace _id: "$email" with _id: null, I get all logins in one result.

Comment: I didn't have to use new Date(), maybe I'm using some other version of mongodb. For the sum of all logins, you indeed have to put null (or a string, or int, just no variable) in the _id field